# Filtering: Show checked filter that only has exacly same attribute for each category (jquery)

Tags: jquery, filtering

How to make filter works like this picture ?

[image]

```
JSFIDDLE
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ar3PY/103/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below working code.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vks9009/13khjkey/)

```
return category == 'color' ? '[data-filter]:contains(", ' + this.value + '"), [data-filter]:contains("' + this.value + ',")' : '[data-filter*="' + this.value + '"]';
```